# How to Integrate Crashlytics with React Native app

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, crashlytics

I'm building my app using React Native and I want to catch crashes that happen on both Objective-C and JavaScript sides of the app.

I installed Crashlytics SDK using their guide and installer and everything went smooth. I do get to see crashes from the Objective-C side, but **not** crashes that occurs from JavaScript.

Do I need to do something special to catch JavaScript errors and report them to Crashlytics?

Thanks,
Ran.

Comment: Were you testing from a "release" build of the app?

Comment: Yes, I did. That's how I verified that Crashes from Objective-C reported but not JavaScript.

Comment: When the JavaScript error occurred did you app show a redbox or completely crash?

Comment: It completely crashed :(

Comment: When it crashed did it show a obj-c looking crash or nothing at all in crash lyrics?

Comment: I don't believe Crashlytics reports JS crashes? Is there documentation saying that it's supposed to?

Comment: @jamesfzhang the only thing I found is this comment
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1665#issuecomment-135660922

Comment: Have you tried Sentry ? https://docs.getsentry.com/hosted/clients/javascript/integrations/react-native/

Comment: Actually yes, that what I settled on. Currently Sentry is the only provider that support React Native.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just wrote a blog post about this:

[Add Crashlytics to your React Native iOS app](https://medium.com/delivery-com-engineering/add-crashlytics-to-your-react-native-ios-app-69a983a9062a#.mgkuycqxu)

The approach I took was to override the logging function of react native to be able to log my own stuff and see it on the crash logs and also generated a sourcemap in order to the see full stack trace.

Comment: Thanks, I already settled on Sentry which works great :)
But good to see Crashlytics integration as well, nice job!

Comment: Thanks Can you please update your blog now firebase merge with fabric.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [react-native-fabric](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fabric) It has a good guide and has js methods for both crashlytics and answer